# CocoalibSpotify how to monitor playback rate change due to network lost

Tags: ios, spotify, cocoalibspotify-2.0

I'm using cocoalibspotify and I'm trying to monitor the playback stop/pause due to temporary network lost.  In that case the spotify will stop playing.
I tried to observe "playbackManager.isPlaying" key change, but it only changes when i manually change it or the track is finished, didn't catch any playback stop due to network connection.
Thank you for your help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

After play around with the spotify sdk a bit, I found the callback function in SPSessionPlaybackDelegate:
-(void)session:(SPSession *)aSession didEncounterNetworkError:(NSError *)error;
That would do the trick.